# Why does my gpx layer go to the wrong spot even if they have the same CRS?

Tags: wgs84, overlay, gpx, coordinate-system

Help! I am a QGIS beginner with a big problem! I am trying to load a gpx file from Garmin into my map.  The project CRS is WGS 84, and the incoming data is in CRS WGS 84.  When I look at the bottom of my map in QGIS or on the coordinate capture, all of  my locations appear to be in the UTM format.  However when I load in the gpx files, the points go to their long/lat locations, which is of course very far away from everything else because everything else as UTM coordinates in the thousands. I have on the fly enabled... but I am not sure how to fix this.  Even if I save the GPX data in coordinate form, it still loads to its lat/long numbers as UTM coordinates.  I am hoping there is an easy fix that I am too inexperienced to know about?

Comment: Welcome to gis.SE. Its hard to tell what is wrong here - can you show a small sample of your data (both the GPX data, and the source data)? Showing which version of QGIS might also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you try the swapping lat/long:

- Load your gpx data
- use the [swapxy plugin](http://planet.qgis.org/plugins/swapXY/) to swap between latitude and longitude
- save the swapped gpx data in any vector format

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have more than only the GPX data:

Rightclick on every layer, and look up the extent values under Properties, metadata tab.

If they are greater than +/- 180/90°, the data is not WGS84, but UTM. Then check `Set CRS for layer`to see if the CRS is set for EPSG:4326 for those **layers** that are limited to +/-180/90, and the UTM of your part of the world for others.

If that does not help you, set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857, add the Openlayers plugin with a Google or Openstreetmap background layer. Then you will see which layer is right and which is misplaced.